# Issue with Elasticsearch geo_bounding_box query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, geolocation

### I'm having an issue getting this query working to filter my search results with a geo_bounding_box query. The first part of the query is working as expected, but adding the filter results in an error:

elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]')

I think the issue could be because of how the data is structured, the *geo_times* object is an array of multiple geo_times objects. I can't figure out the correct syntax for the query. I've searched for that error message for hours and have not been able to find a solution that fits my particular issue. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any input!

### The data looks like:

```
"geo_times" : [
        {
          "node_type" : "unattributed",
          "node_name" : "IP",
          "datetime" : "2017-08-03 18:37:12.275643",
          "relative_time" : "0.268319000"
        },
        {
          "node_type" : "unattributed",
          "node_name" : "PPI Gps",
          "datetime" : "2017-08-03 23:37:30.000000",
          "lat" : "39.2865002",
          "lon" : "-76.6131298",
          "alt" : "12.529"
        },
        {
          "node_type" : "unattributed",
          "node_name" : "IP",
          "datetime" : "2017-08-03 18:37:29.514747",
          "relative_time" : "17.507423000"
        },
        {
          "node_type" : "unattributed",
          "node_name" : "PPI Gps",
          "datetime" : "2017-08-03 23:37:47.000000",
          "lat" : "39.2865282",
          "lon" : "-76.612652",
          "alt" : "9.1669"
        }]
```

### And my query looks like:

```
'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must': [{
            'bool': {
                'should': [{
                    'nested': {
                        'path': 'first_seen_geo_times',
                        'query': {
                            'range': {
                                'first_seen_geo_times.datetime': {
                                    'gte': '2018-04-04',
                                    'lte': '2018-05-04',
                                    'format': 'yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    'nested': {
                        'path': 'last_seen_geo_times',
                        'query': {
                            'range': {
                                'last_seen_geo_times.datetime': {
                                    'gte': '2018-04-04',
                                    'lte': '2018-05-04',
                                    'format': 'yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    },
    'filter': {
        'geo_bounding_box': {
            'geo_times': {
                'top_left': {
                    'lat': 53.69004893827236,
                    'lon': -57.527246475219734
                },
                'bottom_right': {
                    'lat': 30.417758111972528,
                    'lon': -113.23582649230958
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```